Convert class list into list
I have a list which type is <class 'list'>
lst = [
["H", 1.008],
["He", 4.003],
["Li", 6.941],
["Be", 9.012]] 

I want to convert it to a dictionary. The function convert doesn´t work, because of the type class list.
How can I convert it first to a list? And then to a dict?
I tried converting to a list, but don´t find any function for that.

Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a read of the How to Ask section of the help center. I would also recommend you take the tour. Please provide minimal reproducible example and information, which language you are using. Tags in your OP are probably also wrong - check their description.

Convert a list of lists into a dictionary where the first element of each sublist is the key and the second element is the value.
lst = [
    ["H", 1.008],
    ["He", 4.003],
    ["Li", 6.941],
    ["Be", 9.012]
]

# Convert the list of lists into a dictionary
result_dict = dict(lst)

print(result_dict)

Output:
{'H': 1.008, 'He': 4.003, 'Li': 6.941, 'Be': 9.012}

